# How to search a parameter through a different fields in a query string

Tags: apex, soql, sql

```
String leadPhone = lead.phone;
String leadEmail = lead.email;
String qry = 'SELECT a.Id, a.Name,' 
             +'a.Email__c,a.Birth_Date__c,a.Mobile_Phone_Number__c,'
             +'a.Residence_Number__c,a.Work_Number__c'
             +' From Account a WHERE';
```

In the above query string and I wants to search a parameter "lead.phone" among all the 3 
fields either one of them `(Mobile_Phone_Number__c,a.Residence_Number__c,a.Work_Number__c)` also along with that i also need to search an email `"lead.email"` with "`Email__c`" fields. Both the fields `("lead.phone" and "lead.email")` have to be in `OR` conditions.

So far what I tried. but its not giving me Residence_Number__c and Work_Number__c number results

```
 if(lead.phone !=null){       
    qry += ' a.Mobile_Phone_Number__c= :leadPhone OR (a.Residence_Number__c= :leadPhone OR Work_Number__c= :leadPhone)'; 
    }
    if(lead.email !=null && lead.phone !=null){        
    qry += ' OR a.Email__c = :leadEmail';  
    }else if(lead.email!=null){
        qry += ' a.Email__c = :leadEmail';
    }           
    accList = database.query(qry);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in the right direction and please note that this code will become much complex once there are more conditions added.

**Gotchas:**

- If you are dealing with large data sets, make sure that all these fields in where clause are indexed else the query performance will be degraded and with so many OR conditions, if possible consider using an SOSL or two queries, one on phone and one on email
- Sanitize your input before.
- Consider using a library for dynamic [SOQL](https://github.com/PropicSignifi/Query.apex). It may ease some of the tasks.

---

```
String leadPhone;
String leadEmail;
String qry = 'SELECT a.Id, a.Name,'
        + 'a.Email__c,a.Birth_Date__c,a.Mobile_Phone_Number__c,'
        + 'a.Residence_Number__c,a.Work_Number__c'
        + ' From Account a WHERE ';

if (String.isNotBlank(lead.phone)) {
    leadPhone = String.escapeSingleQuotes(lead.phone);
    qry += ' (a.Mobile_Phone_Number__c= :leadPhone OR a.Residence_Number__c= :leadPhone OR Work_Number__c= :leadPhone)';
}

if (String.isNotBlank(lead.email)) {
    if (String.isNotBlank(leadPhone)) {
        qry = qry + ' OR ';
    }
    leadEmail = String.escapeSingleQuotes(lead.email);
    qry += ' a.Email__c = :leadEmail';
}


List<Account> accList = Database.query(qry);
```

Answer (score 1):

The where clause, use the `OR` operator within the `WHERE` clause, but make sure the whole phrase is encapsulated by `()`. If you have other logic like `AND`, etc, not encapsulating the ORs with the parenthesis will give you issues.

So the query should look something like this:

```
SELECT Id, Name
  FROM Account
 WHERE (Email__c = :lead.email OR Mobile_Phone_Number__c = :leadPhone OR a.Residence_Number__c = :leadPhone OR a.Work_Number__c = :leadPhone)
```

I sometimes have issues with using `:variable` and I often just build the query by adding it to the string itself:

```
'WHERE (Email__c = \'' + lead.email + '\' OR Mobile_Phone_Number__c = \'' + leadPhone + '\' OR a.Residence_Number__c = \'' + leadPhone + '\' OR a.Work_Number__c = \'' + leadPhone + '\')';
```